# Can't set data-icon alignment and padding

Tags: html, css, fonts, symbols, webfonts

I downloaded a symbol from Fontastic and I've added it in my html with

```
<a href="#">SHOW MORE NEWS <span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="a"></span></a>
```

The problem is the symbol is 18px x 20px. It adds unwanted space in the `<a>` element, and I can't add padding or align it with the text.

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you have an example? JSFiddle, Codepen, etc.

Comment: Here it is, https://jsfiddle.net/q0pjj0jb/, but I can't make the symbol work. I've added font files and css, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would probably be to position your icon absolute, so it gets lifted out of the flow and doesn't affect the parent `a` anymore. Something like this should do the trick:

```
[data-icon="a"] {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
}
a {
  position: relative;
}
```

You may want to use some different selectors, but you get the idea...

I've set up a small fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/1wsuc7ns/

**update:**
You commented that you only see part of the symbol. That is somewhat strange since the above code should not affect the size of the symbol in any way. Perhaps there is some other css at play here. The first thing that comes to mind is an `overflow:hidden;` on the `a`. Give the following code a try:

```
[data-icon="a"] {
  position: absolute; 
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
a {
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

So I added some extra space for the icon inside the `a` tag (you may have to play with the number a bit) and changed the positioning to keep the symbol inside the `a`.

Another problem could be that there is something covering up the symbol. You could try adding a reasonably high `z-index` to the symbol to see if that solves it.

Not much more I can tell without looking at the actual rendered page...

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I can only see only half of the symbol. If you had the chance to see my fiddle, download the font files and running it on local, you could see the problem

Comment: have a look at the update. Perhaps you can share a screenshot of what you mean by "half of the symbol" or even set up a demo somewhere that reproduces the issue.

Comment: I'm sorry, I was unable to see it because white color on white background. The real problem is `data-icon` element is outside the parent element. If I add a background color to the parent `<a>` it won't be applied to `data-icon`. Even if I wrap them within a `<div>` with background-color. You can easily see the problem in your jsfiddle: see where it ends `background-color` property

Comment: And.. what if I wanted to align it? i tried vertical-align with no success